# Reading in json file and storing json information c++

Tags: c++, json

I am using nlohmann json which can be found here

https://github.com/nlohmann/json#integration

I am trying to read in json data from a file, here is an part of the dictLoad1.json file

EDIT: So I figured out that even though file name is producing the correct string, the file for nlogmann is not opening. If anyone knows how to get the file to open, I could use the help. I will update if I figure it out.

```
"dictionary": [
   {"word": "MEAGRE", "definition": "A large European scinoid fish (Scina umbra or S. aquila),having white bloodless flesh. It is valued as a food fish. [Writtenalso maigre.]"},
    {"word": "GRUGRU WORM", "definition": "The larva or grub of a large South American beetle (Calandrapalmarum), which lives in the pith of palm trees and sugar cane. Itis eaten by the natives, and esteemed a delicacy."},
    {"word": "POSTPONEMENT", "definition": "The act of postponing; a deferring
```

From that github website here is how it says to read input from a json file and store it into a json variable-

```
// read a JSON file
std::ifstream i("file.json");
json j;
i >> j;
```

Here is my code trying to read in the json file

```
        string filename = line.substr(input.size()+8, line.size());
        filename[4] = toupper(filename[4]);
        cout << filename << "\n"; //printing dictLoad1.json

        std::ifstream i(filename); 
        json j;
        i >> j;
```

The code breaks at the line i >> j

for nlohmann at the top of the file I do have the

```
#include "json.hpp" 
using json = nlohmann::json;
```

the exact error is

```
[json.exception.parse_error.101] parse error at 1: syntax error - unexpected end of input; expected '[', '{', or a literal
Makefile:36: recipe for target 'test' failed
```